# Can Redfish be used to wipe hard drives

Tags: bmc

I am wondering if can Redfish (Dell or Lenovo) be used to format/wipe clean hard drives. I haven't been able to find any examples. If it's not possible, what is the alternative approach other than Refish to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: boot any Linux live CD/USB drive